# Unable to run apk file on device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, 2d-games

First I created 2d game for web in `Unity`. Now I have created `.apk` file for android devices using build option in `Unity`. But when I run this apk file on my device its only show blank screen and then game close. No errors. But why I am getting blank screen instead of my game. Whats wrong? Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way for you to access the debug console of your Android device? If so, you should see some hints why your app is not loading.

Comment: @Huxley I dont know how to do this.

Comment: You should download and install the Android SDK [from here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238) you find an example of how to use it.

Comment: I already have SDK in my system and I install api libraries.